# Amazon RDS end point need to attach under the EC2 instance using CloudFormation template

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, amazon-rds

When creating AWS infrastructure using a CloudFormation template under EC2 instance required to attach RDS end point in the User Data section.

This is for a new EC2 instance with RDS MYSQL. I tried using export option but not working:

```
export DB_HOST=${Databas.Endpoint.Address}
export DB_PASSWORD=${DatabasePassword}
```

I was expecting: `1234.erer.awsDNSname`

The output is not appending into User Data.

Comment: Your question is a little confusing. What do you mean by "using a CloudFormation template under EC2 instance"? Are you creating a CloudFormation template to launch an Amazon EC2 instance? Can you edit your question to show more of the code you are using and to explain more about what you are trying to do and what problems you are facing?

Comment: Ec2 instance also creating using CF

Comment: So, are you saying that you are "Creating a CloudFormation stack that launches an Amazon EC2 instance, and in that instance you want to define some User Data that includes the Endpoint and Password of an Amazon RDS database"? Is that correct? And is the RDS database also being created in the same stack?

Comment: Yeap, Also those details need to attach for the EC2 instance in the Environment variable(permanently)  like export Database_HOST=${Database.Endpoint.Address}
            export DB_PASSWORD=${DatabasePassword}

Comment: How are you intending to use those exported environment variables? Are you expecting them to be available to scripts that are later run on the instance (outside of User Data), or will they be used elsewhere within the same User Data script?

Comment: these values required under the Environments variable for .bahsrc   to append

Comment: Can you please edit your question to show how you are using the values? Preferably a minimal example that shows how you are wanting to write the values to disk. Please include the full definition of the User Data field, since it needs `!Sub` to be active.